# SQL UPDATE with LIKE

Tags: mysql, database

I was trying to update approx 20,000 records in a table by using statements like this one,
however, I got the message say `0 row(s) affected` so it didn't work.

```
UPDATE nc_files SET title ="Worklog details" WHERE "log_name" LIKE "%PC01%"
```

The `log_name` field has all the file names with mixed file extensions and cases ,e.g.

```
PC01.TXT | Worklog details

PC02.txt | Project Summary

PC03.DOC| Worklog details

PC04.doc| Project Summary
```

The reason why I need to use `LIKE` is that the updated file only have file name without extension, e.g.

```
PC01 | Worklog details

PC02 | Project Summary
```

How do I update records by using `LIKE`?

Comment: Did you try to select rows? SELECT * FROM nc_files  WHERE log_name LIKE "%PC01%"

Comment: first, try performing a select statement with the same WHERE clause, this will prove if your where clause matches any rows on your target table. are you sure the case matches?, e.g. is the data held as lower case and your where clause uses UPPER CASE?

Comment: Your question has been answered. As an additional suggestion, if your updated file contains file names without extension, I suggest to change your LIKE clause as follows: `WHERE log_name LIKE "PC01%"`. This will make sure that indexes (if any is present) are used, making queries faster.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `log_name` is a field name, remove literal quotes from it -

```
UPDATE nc_files SET title ="Worklog details" WHERE log_name LIKE "%PC01%"
```

Answer (score 3):

this is because your column name `log_name` should not be in `'` quotes.

`"log_name" LIKE "%PC01%"` condition will always fail and zero rows will get updated, try this:

```
UPDATE nc_files 
SET title ="Worklog details" 
WHERE log_name LIKE "%PC01%";
```

Answer (score 1):

By default MySQL allows double quoted names to be understood as *either* identifiers (like column names) or as string literals.

This is meant as a convenience, but I find the semantic ambiguity frustrating.  MySQL must resolve the ambiguity, and cannot magically always guess the coder's intention, as you discovered.

```
-- In default sql_mode under 5.5
--
SELECT "foo"           -- "foo" is a *column* if tbl.foo exists, otherwise a string 
  FROM "tbl"           -- Oops!  ER_PARSE_ERROR (1064)  Can't do this in default mode.
 WHERE "foo" = "foo";  -- Both of these are strings
```

So, the way around it is to force unambiguous interpretation of identifiers:

1. Do not quote simple identifiers
2. Use MySQL-specific backticks for quoting
   (This is ODBC's SQL_IDENTIFIER_QUOTE_CHAR)
3. Always override the change the `sql_mode` to include [ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) (or a superset of it)
   Double quotes are then exclusively for identifiers, single quotes for strings.

#3 is my personal favorite, for readability and portability.  The problem is it tends to surprise people who only know MySQL, and you have to remember to override the default.

Answer (score 0):

```
"log_name" should not be in quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar trouble. The problem are the quotations marks "
I Fixed my code as follow.

UPDATE Table SET Table.Field = "myreplace"
WHERE (((Table.Field) Like '%A-16%'));

Regards, Alexwin1982

Answer (score 0):

Try replace keyword 
UPDATE `nc_files` SET `title` = REPLACE(`title`, 'PC01', 'Worklog details') WHERE log_name LIKE '%PC01%'