# how to update a row in a table starting from a charater like "E"

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I have a sample table in which an ID starts from characters like "C", "D", and "E". Now I only need to update a row which has an ID Starting from "E". Please Help

Comment: same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176824/sql-update-with-like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET FIELD = VALUE WHERE UPPER(ID) LIKE 'E%'
```