# PHP mysql update query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update  a table name demo using mysql update but its not working.
here is my php code..

**PHP MYSQL CODING:**

```
    $sql1 = 'UPDATE demo
    SET name="$name", dob="$dob"
    WHERE mid = "$id" AND email = "$email" ';

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: Show us the code where your variables are defined. What error do you get? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Variables aren't expanded inside single-quoted strings, only double-quoted strings.

Comment: `mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error())` will probably tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I am getting all the post values even I got a positive result in $result1 variable...but the database didn't show any update...Some thing very unusual.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $sql1 = 'UPDATE table_name
    SET name="'. $name .'", dob="'. $dob '."
    WHERE mid = "'. $id .'" AND email = "'. $email .'" ';
```

You will need to escape the '. If you would have changes it around so that " was the outer qouation mark and ' was the inner it would have worked.

Comment: In other words, OP needs to RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thank you for the help but still not working..

Comment: Double check everything, the mid $id must exist (on the same row as) email is exactly $email. that said, you may try to change operator on the email string, from an equal sign to the LIKE operator, also if mid is uniqe, email is not nessecary. If the caracter set does not match it's not equal. See mehaase's answer over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176824/sql-update-with-like

Please note that the mysql_* functions are deprecated

Comment: Sorry but still straggle with the problem?

Comment: the php files are having the data when I echo manually its gives the result but its not updating the database

Comment: Could you paste your current code into pastebin or a fiddle?

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me .....the issue is resolved, it was a UI problem which I solved.

Answer (score 1):

Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. So switch your quotes:

```
$sql1 = "UPDATE demo
SET name='$name', dob='$dob'
WHERE mid = '$id' AND email = '$email' ";
```

Comment: I am getting the update notification but its not make any changes in the database...

Comment: Does `mysql_error()` show any error?

Comment: no! that's why i mention unusual problem ...hahaha

Comment: If you `echo $sql1` and execute it by hand, does it work?

Comment: yes its giving me the result but not showing in the db

Comment: I run query in db its working I think there some other problem to show the result ..let me check thank u..

Answer (score 0):

The big problem you are facing is, you used the wrong quotation marks. When you are using only the double ones, it'll work. But when you setted the code in single quotation marks, it uses all variables as string. I'll search for "$id" and not for the value $id stands for.

Right code:

```
$sql1 = 'UPDATE table_name
SET name= "'.$name.'", dob="'.$dob.'"
WHERE mid = "'.$id.'" AND email = "'.$email.'" ';

$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
```