# How do I run Update Query in MySQL and replace a matching string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I tried a couple of things but it deleted the complete content from the column.

Here's what I want to do - A particular table [abc_tablename] in my MySQL database has a column [xyz_columnname] that has a lot of email IDs (more than 5000) and I want them to replace all the email IDs with a text [email ID removed]

I used the following query for SELECT:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM abc_tablename
 WHERE xyz_columnname LIKE '%@%'
```

How do I perform the replace function in this case? Can you help me with the query for the same. I tried this but it removed all the data from xyz_columnname

```
UPDATE abc_tablename 
   SET xyz_columnname = REPLACE (  xyz_columnname,  LIKE ''%@%'',  '**email ID removed**');
```

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to run these queries. Also, do note that xyz_columnname has a lot of text and numeric content along with the email ID.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL UPDATE with LIKE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176824/sql-update-with-like)

Comment: Is the value in `xyz_columnname` just an email address and nothing else? Or is it an email address among a bunch of other text like `blah blah test@example.com blah` and you only want to replace the email in that text? If that is the case, you would likely need to use a regular expression to perform a replace. Mysql doesn't have a built in regexp replace function so you would need to use something like php and update it or define a udf version of regexp_replace (there are several out there).

Comment: @JonathanKuhn You mentioned it correct. The xyz_columnname has a lot of text and numeric content along with the email ID.

Comment: @ravichopra, well, like I said above, mysql doesn't have the capability out of the box to do pattern match and replace. You would either need to use something else like php and preg_replace to pull out all the rows where like `%@%`, fix them and update the rows one at a time or implement one of the many regexp_replace user defined functions within mysql use that. The latter would likely be more performant, but if you are doing this as a one off thing, just brute force it the easier way with php and in the future, fix it before insert.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this command, this will update all rows which column `xyz_columnname` contains an `@` to show `email ID Removed`

```
UPDATE abc_tablename 
    SET `xyz_columnname` = 'email ID removed'
    WHERE `xyz_columnname` LIKE '%@%'
```

> Use ` (backquotes) for column name
>
> Use ' or " for values
>
> Don't use backticks with column values. use either single or double quotes otherwise mysql will consider that value as a column name.

Comment: Will this work even if the xyz_columnname has has a lot of text and numeric content along with the email ID?

Comment: No, this will only work if `xyz_columnname` only contains email address. You didnt make that clear in your question that `xyz_columnname` contained multiple types of information. This is not best practice for SQL, you should use a separate column for each value.